# SQL Server RowNumbering

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SrNo   TextCol
--------------
NULL   ABC
NULL   ABC
NULL   ASC
NULL   qwe
```

I want to update the `SrNo` column with numbers 1,2,3,4 without changing sequence of other columns.

Comment: Can you share output for examples with other textcol like `cza,cbc`...

Comment: Really, there's nothing to change or keep. Sql table is unordered set of rows. The only way to order rows is to specify explicit ORDER BY in a query.

Comment: What version of sql server are you using? Do you have a clustered index on the table? If you are using sql server 2012 or above, you can use sequences to insert those values into your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables are unordered, so you cannot rely on "existing sequence". However a "trick" is to use `select null` which in effect does nothing to the row order. While it works you should not rely on it as a permanent solution.

```
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT SrNo, TextCol
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select NULL)) rn
        FROM yourTable
     )
UPDATE cte
SET SrNo = rn;
```

Answer (score 1):

It only makes sense to speak of using row number if there exist a column which can provide ordering.  Assuming the ordering is specified by the `TextCol` column, then we can try the following:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT SrNo, TextCol, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TextCol) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

UPDATE cte
SET SrNo = rn;
```